# Terraform has no tagging feature when creating Redshift parameter group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, terraform

When creating redshift parameter group using Terraform, tagging is not supported. I do not know why terraform designs this way.
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/redshift_parameter_group.html

I DO need to make redshift parameter group tagged after run "terraform apply". I am thinking maybe I should add tag from null_resource part, maybe using AWS CLI, etc. But I am not sure how to do that. Does anybody have the similar issue and figure out how to make redshift parameter group tagged after "terraform apply"? Thanks.

Comment: Terraform will always be behind on AWS features support. This is one such example. Try using the `local-exec` provisioner to run a CreateTags on the created resource.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Krishna Kumar R. will run AWS CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html

Comment: You can use a null resource as well to use the AWS CLI to tag the resource https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html

Comment: @Krishna Kumar R and strongjz: do you know how to create tags on redshift parameter group? I think I should use: "aws create-tags
--resource-name <value> --tags <value>" but I do not know what is the value of the --resource-name. according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/create-tags.html, it should be sth. like arn:aws:redshift:us-east-1:123456789:cluster:t1, for redshift param group, what should I put after the 123456789? Thanks.

Comment: I have figured out. see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the following command in null_resource->local-exec->command, and it works:

```
aws redshift create-tags --resource-name arn:aws:redshift:<region>:<account_id>:parametergroup:<parameter_group_name> --tags Key=XX,Value=XXX Key=XXXX,Value=XXXXX
```